# Execution of a SQL Server stored procedure failed

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, stored-procedures, doctrine-orm

As mentionned in the title, I have some troubles to execute an SQL Server stored procedure with my Symfony2 application.

This one work if I execute it directly on the server.
But when I want to use it tanks to Doctrine, I've got an SQL statement error :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2812 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [2812] (severity 16) [(null)]

After a quick research, seems to indicate that stored procedure doesn't exist in database.
But this is not the case, since I can execute it directly on the server (with correct result).

Here exactly why Symfony2 returns:

```
DBALException: An exception occurred while executing ' EXEC SP_GET_PRICE
@p_id_variation = ?,
@p_quantity = ?,
@p_selling_price_type = ?,
@p_date = ?,
@p_id_clients = ?' with params [8933, 1, 2, "2014-03-31T10:11:01", 0]:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2812 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [2812] (severity 16) [(null)]
```

After mutiples researches, I've no idea on how to resolve it...

Thanks! :)

***Edit***: I use [PDOLibBundle](https://github.com/trooney/PDODblibBundle) to connect to my SQL Server

Comment: Is there any stored proc that you **can** execute in the same database? What if you call the proc with dbo.sp_get_price?

Comment: I've just tested, and yes I can execute an other stored procedure... So the problem seems to be specific to this one. This is already a good news! ;)

I tried an exec with dbo.sp_get_price too, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the SP with the same user you used to connect from your application. If no, does the application user's have permission to run the SP?

Comment: Yes, user is the same.
I actually look why I can execute another procedure without error, since there's no syntax error in this one :/

Comment: Try to use the full name of the SP DBName.Schema.SPName

Comment: OK, I had no time to explain it: avoid using the 'sp_' prefix for stored procs. The prefix is a special one for system stored procedures. When you call a system proc (EXEC sp_*), the SQL Server will search for it in the master database. You can order the SQL Server to use your database by using fully qualified names.

The best solution is to avoid using the sp_ prefix. Use usp_ instead .

Comment: It actually tries to locate the proc in resource database first, not the master. At least since the resource db was introduced :) Not even that if you schema-qualify. And IMHO best not tu use any prefix at all, VerbObject or vice versa is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Error 2018 is "Could not find stored procedure". Ensure you spelled it correctly.